# Last tableView cell not touchable after migrating existing app to be iPhone 5 compatible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to figure out why the last cell in my app's tableView isn't touchable while running on the iPhone 5, as it works fine on the previous iPhones and also iPads. I migrated this app and found this bug while testing on the device and simulator. No code change was necessary to migrate the app. Screenshot below:

If you can help me at all, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S98BS.jpg

Comment: Still no answer to your problem? I have a similar issue!

Comment: The issue has been resolved. What is your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you use xib for iPhone 4 and it's touch content Is ending above last cell? If you use storyboard or xib you need to create new with 1136x640 resolution.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I overlooked the .xib size!